# Singleton gets disposed

Tags: flutter

I have the class:

```
class DeviceDao {
 //singleton
 static final DeviceDao _singleton = DeviceDao._( );

 static DeviceDao get instance => _singleton;

  DeviceDao._( ) {
    print("CREATING INSTANCE");


}
   ...... class data somes here
   }
```

I need to access one and only one instance around the application. At some point "CREATING INSTANCE" is printed twice which means that my singleton got disposed. There is no setter for _singleton anywhere in the app. Obsiously all class data becomes null value at this point. Under what circumstances such singleton can get disposed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to defined your Singleton at this way:

```
 class DeviceDao {
     //singleton
     static final DeviceDao _singleton = DeviceDao._( );

     factory DeviceDao() => _singleton;

     DeviceDao._( ) {
        print("CREATING INSTANCE");
     }
   ...... class data somes here
 }
```

Then you can access your Singleton anywhere with just calling the Class function:

```
DeviceDao().someClassMethod()
```

Use Factory when you don't want to return the initialized class itself, which is does. It is just returning the static singleton variable, which was allocated during compilation time, so only one static variable exists.

Comment: I tried. No luck. It is the same. Constructor called twice. This drives me crazy. Fun fact: other two singletons work as expected.

Comment: I found it! I have been using "compute". Seems that compute has no idea of static the existing singleton. (somewhere in my faded memories I may recall that calling compute is a separate app). I keep your solution in my app as it is shorter a syntax.